# EF 4. Select two-level hierarchy by means of LINQ to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

There is the Cars entity set and every Car has a set of AdvancedCodes.
Lately I used method notation to select hierarchy from my EF storage. It looked like this:

```
repository.Cars.Where(a => a.AgentId == userAgent.AgentId)
      .Include(a => a.AdvancedCodes)
      .Where(a => a.CarId != null).ToList()
```

I recieved collection of Cars with collection of AdvancedCodes within every Car. It was great.
Now I need to switch to LINQ-to-Entities notation to perform multiple LEFT joins and more complicated SELECT:

```
from cr in context.Cars
from ac in context.AdvancedCodes.Where(a => a.CarId == cr.CarId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from c in context.Contacts.Where(a => a.AdvancedCodeId == ac.AdvancedCodeId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from ag in context.Agents.Where(a => a.AgentId == ac.AdvancedCodeId).DefaultIfEmpty()
where ac.AgentId == agentId && ac.CarId != null && cr.IsApproved == true
select new CarCodeModel
{
     CarBrand = cr.CarBrand.BrandName,
     RegNumber = cr.RegNumber, 
     ContactDate = c.DateCreated,
     ContactCode = ac.Code,
     CodeCreationDate = ac.DateCreated,
     IsUsed = c.CoId != null,
     RecepientName = ag.AgentName
};
```

That is OK but this time I get a flat 2D set of data that I need somehow iterate and split on two related collections. Is there any way to write more sophisticated query to get the same two-level set of collections like it was after the .Include method?

Comment: Why do you **have** to switch to LINQ-to-Entities notation to perform that query?

Comment: Because I know how to write the query only in this way.